# windbg refuses to load symbols for dump (Unable to verify timestamp)

Tags: debugging, windbg, stack-trace, symbols

I open a particular crash dump in windbg, set the symbol path, load the exception record, and produce a stack walk with `k`. I get a wrong call stack, even though i know the symbols do match.

The output of `lmi` is full of lines like `00007ff7'6f3c0000 00007ff7'743f0000   WhateverModule T (private pdb symbols)  WhateverModule.dll`, note the `T` there. According to the documentation, it means:

> The timestamp is missing, not accessible, or equal to zero.

This checks out with what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100390/in-windbg-what-can-cause-the-message-warning-unable-to-verify-timestamp-for-m/9118342#9118342), indeed i did not specify a binary path. Even though the dump seems to contain all the timestamps for all the relevant modules (for instance, lmDvmWhateverModule outputs

```
[...]
    Timestamp:        Mon Jun 15 13:18:45 2015 (557EB495)
    CheckSum:         04F8AF3B
[...]
```

) involved in the stacktrace, the debugger still complains. If i feed it a correct binary search path, then i get a correct callstack.

My questions are:

1. Even though the timestamps are right there in the dump, windbg complains about them missing. Why?
2. I thought PDBs are matched with binaries comparing a GUID and a so-called age. Why does windbg refuse to load symbols blaming missing information that it actually has, and does not need? :)

My windbg version is 10.0.10240.9

Comment: What are your `.symopt`s? Did you do a `.reload` after setting the symbol path?

Comment: `SYMOPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE, SYMOPT_UNDNAME, SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS, SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES, SYMOPT_OMAP_FIND_NEAREST, SYMOPT_NO_UNQUALIFIED_LOADS, SYMOPT_FAIL_CRITICAL_ERRORS, SYMOPT_AUTO_PUBLICS, SYMOPT_NO_IMAGE_SEARCH`, and yes.

Comment: `!sym noisy` may give you more information.

Comment: According to `!sym noisy`, symbols are okay (e.g. `*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for WhateverModule.dll
DBGHELP: WhateverModule - private symbols & lines 
[path]\WhateverModule.pdb. `

Comment: +1 for !sym noisy. Also note that when loading a crash dump the debugger first uses the module name/size/date to find the PE files in the symbol server, and then uses the GUID/age in the PE files to find the PDBs. Two steps. I've documented some of the details here:
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/symbols-the-microsoft-way/

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this. I just don't get _why_ windbg would need the images themselves. According to `lmDvm`, it has the timestamps, checksums, image sizes, and of course module names for all relevant modules. I think it has the GUIDs as well, because `!sym noisy` outputs that the PDBs are matching. windbg just somehow refuses to use them blaming missing timestamps.

Comment: Normally a minidump just has MINIDUMP_MODULE which does not include the GUID and age. Without seeing the minidump I can only speculate. Either the GUI/age/pdb name are there, but ignored, or they are not there.

Why do you want to load minidumps without having the PE files? That is not recommended.

Comment: I want to avoid loading images because they are not strictly needed for a stackwalk (PDBs contain copies of unwind tables). Note that i'm not using a symbol server (i know It would be more than a good idea to set one up, but that's beyond of the scope of this question). The GUIDs/ages must be in the minidump, because if i feed windbg an incorrect symbol path on purpose (another build of the same product), i get `DBGHELP:  [path]\WhateverModule.pdb - mismatched pdb`, while with the correct sympath i get `DBGHELP: WhateverModule - private symbols & lines [path]\WhateverModule.pdb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the assumption that unwind information is present in PDB files. I was wrong, it isn't (by default). However, it turns out there is a linker switch which instructs the linker to copy unwind data into PDBs: `/DEBUGTYPE:PDATA`

All you need to do is add `/DEBUGTYPE:CV,PDATA` to your linker switches (according to the  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823750.aspx), `/DEBUGTYPE:CV` is the default for user mode programs compiled with `/DEBUG`).

After this, windbg has no problem doing stackwalks, even with binaries missing (made sure with `!sym noisy` and `lmvm` that binaries are indeed not found). Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Visual Studio (tried with 2015 Update 3).